# How to print lines from file if lines are given in list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm fairly new to python (using 2.7) so I realize this might be an obvious solution. I'm writing this more to work through the issue on "paper" so to speak.

I have a file containing several different instances of a phrase (phrase="xy Coordinates") and successfully created lists containing the start and end lines of each instance of these coordinates. My question is, now that I have these lists how would I iterate over them to print each line of the coordinate?

This is what I have so far.

```
def printCart(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
            CStart=[]
            CEnd=[]
            for i in range(len(slist)):
                    start=slist[i]+5
                    end=start+int(num)-1
                    CStart.append(start)
                    CEnd.append(end)
            return CStart,CEnd
```

Comment: If you're "fairly new to python": DO NOT LEARN PYTHON 2! It's a dead language that went out of support two years ago. Learn Python 3, which is the only supported version of the language at present.

Comment: Additionally: I have no idea what you're doing here, and the code does not constitute a [MCVE]; you open a file and never use it, you refer to `slist` and `num` without defining them, etc. This is thoroughly useless for understanding what you're doing. My guess is you just want `zip` (although for performance on 2.7, you need to do either `from future_builtins import zip` or `from itertools import izip as zip` to get the sane version from Python 3).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Sorry about not defining the variables, I wasn't really sure how formatting/requirements work on this site. I started on python 3 but for this project I'm working on I only have 2.7 available. Thanks again! - (Edit to add- I see what you mean about me including the open(filename) on that particular section, I had originally been using it for the enumerate(f) function but changed it, so it was just an obsolete part of the code that wasn't doing anything)

Comment: "I only have 2.7 available" Why? (Are you also forced to use Windows 7 to run your computer?)

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate through a list and print each element, you can do (suppose your list is called CStart):

```
for element in CStart:
    print element
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a pretty easy fix, now I just need to figure out how to give each list a different iterative name. Typing out the problem actually helps!

```
def finalprint(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
            lines=f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                    cart=[]
                    for element in CSlist:
                            if lines[element] in CElist:
                                    break
                            else:
                                    c=lines[element].strip().split()
                                    del c[0:1]
                                    cart.append(c)
    return cart
```